# Overriding a method with different signature

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

Have a look at the following example:

```
Class A{

virtual foo(int& a){ cout << "this is A";}

}


Class B: public A{
foo(int a){cout << "this is B";}
}
```

inside the Main section:

```
int prm= 6;

A* myA= new B();

myA->foo(prm);
```

when I test this code, It seems like the foo method of A is the one which takes place,
even if I change the signiture of foo to take "int" at A and "double" at B and use myA.foo(5.5) it still uses A's foo.
Can you explain to me what happens "behind the scenes", why does the compiler assumes that my desired method is A's foo even though the dynamic type of myA is B?

Note that in this question I use A* myA, and therefore myA's static type is the base class. In the question marked as duplicate, there is use of B* myA (the static type of the object is the derived class, and not the base class). This code compiles (again, differs from the question marked as duplicate), but behaves in an unexpected manner at **runtime**.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the other question, you simply have a bug: in the line `A myA= new B();` you create a temporary `B` and then copy construct `myA` with it. `myA` is not a `B`, it's an `A`. You want to use pointers or references here. Try `A *myA= new B();`

Comment: @Fozi, the code shouldn't even compile with `A myA = new B()`

Comment: @vsoftco You're right, I missed that `new`. Anyways it's not an inheritance problem.

Comment: I've updated the pointer, It should have been there, did not change the result

Comment: @Shperb, that's because the signature of `B::foo(int)` is not the same as `A::foo(int&)`, so effectively the compiler generates a new function, i.e. overloading, and NOT overriding the virtual one from `A`. In C++11, you can use the `override` keyword to ensure that indeed you are overriding (and not overloading) your virtual function. If you declare `B::foo(int) override {...}`, you'll get a compile time error, the compiler complaining that this is not an override but an overload.